# Domain Driven Design implementation issue between modeling and coding

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am studying hard DDD now. After months of studying, I found a contradiction between modeling and coding. As you know, DDD has the principle of "Domain 1st, Tech 2nd". However, there are "definite" constraints when moving the actual model into the implementation, for example:

Original model:

[image]

With the domain concept, posts are associated with multiple comments, and comments are an ordinary model that depends on the post. Moving this into code ...

```
class Post{
    Integer postId;
    String title;
    String content;
    String writer;
    Collection<Comment> comments;
}
class Comment{
    String content;
}
```

Like this... But if there are hundreds of millions of comments, there will be performance problems. According to the solution I have investigated, finally I change the original model as follows....

Revised model:

[image]

Also the code will change...

```
class Post{
    Integer postId;
    String title;
    String content;
    String writer;
}
class Comment{
    Integer postId;
    String content;
}
```

This revised model works well for me and I am satisfied with the solution. But I feel something inconsistent. It seems that the model is distorting due to technical constraints. If we show the first and second models to the domain experts and talk about the diagram, he or she will better understand the first model.

Am I misunderstanding about DDD concept? If so, give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: You're lucky to have domain experts who understand UML so well :)

Comment: The domain expert shouldn't have to know anything about UML or code at all. That's the whole idea of DDD and the ubiquitous language. Check my response below.

Comment: Of course, I'm still learning DDD and not actually working on real world, but I've heard that people are communicate with a domain expert through a UML(using whiteboard...) ....? isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the changes in mindset that come with Domain Driven Design is that your domain will constantly evolve with changes to your understanding of the domain.  It is not just that the domain will evolve, but your understanding and perception about it will evolve, as well.

What you are running into right now, in my opinion, is trying to rationalize the design based on the loading of one or more entities into an aggregate by looking at it from how it is persisted.  This common parent and child relationship feels natural, because it is the way that most of us have done things in the past.  Even from a DDD perspective, it is easy to get caught up in the "Comments can't exist without Posts" paradigm.

This comes down to the fact that you are modelling based upon data inside of the domain, instead of use cases.  Look at it this way...  Posts are not simply a collection of Comments.  Instead, a Comment *refers* to a specific Post.  The nuance sounds minor, but it has broad-reaching consequences.  When modeled in this fashion, it matches your revised model - and it is completely and totally fine.  The only thing you need to change is your mindset, being that Comment can be considered an Aggregate, just as a Post is.  They both are going to have use cases where the other one must exist, but at the same time, you need to see that you are unlikely to do something where both are impacted as part of the same use case (outside of deletion of the Post).

To illustrate, consider this use case:

*As a Writer, I want to be able to edit the Content of my Post.*

Your new model actually effectively supports that.  Instead of looking at the relationship, you are looking at how the domain is used.  Should you load Comments for a Writer to edit?  Without knowing your domain, I would still assume that you would not want to do so.  There are use cases that will likely involve both Posts and Comments, and that is also fine.  Since you have two Aggregates inside of a single Bounded Context, you will be able to support use cases that are solely based on Posts, solely based on Comments, or a combination of both.

In terms of the technical concerns, you mention "hundreds of millions of comments".  I assume that you mean system-wide, and not for a single Post?  Assume that you have an active post, and that it sees 20k comments in its lifetime.  For a properly designed and optimized database, this should still not be an issue.  When it becomes an issue, if it ever does, it can be further addressed by additional changes to the technology used, as opposed to changing the domain.  You can look at things like caching strategies (outside of the domain, since that is an application concern and not a domain concern), external indexes, eventual consistency, etc.

Highly recommend taking a read through Vaughn Vernon's "Effective Aggregate Design" series of articles, if you have not already:

- [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838)

Additionally, his excellent book "Implementing Domain-Driven Design", is a must-read, in my opinion.  While the Evans material is essential, it is more like the theoretical concepts; whereas the Vernon material talks about how to put the concepts into practice and what the implications of those decisions are.

**As an addendum, like plalx points out in the comments below.**  None of this is meant to be a generalization about Posts and Comments in general, but explicitly how they apply to your domain, as it has been described to us and what could be inferred from your models.  Posts and Comments will likely behave differently for others, because others will have distinct use cases.  Even within your own domain, should Posts and/or Comments exist in a different context, they could behave differently.  Above all else, try and make sure that everything you add to your domain model (in general) is added because of a specific and direct use case.  It is tempting to simply start data modeling, but you will start to find yourself trying to force use cases into the domain model.  Domain modeling should not be a finite process, or a single step in the process.  Be willing and able to adapt to changes in understanding or changes to the way that the business changes its overall operational strategies over time.

Comment: "Posts are not simply a collection of Comments. Instead, a Comment refers to a specific Post" This may be true in this case, but you cannot generalize that `Comment` may never be an entity that lives within an AR in every domains. I think you need to put more emphasis on why this design is acceptable, given the business processes and invariants (which we do not know, but can assume for the sake of the example). Explaining an example where `Comment` would have to be an entity rather than an AR in a fictionnal domain would help.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I tried to stress that the design should be driven by use cases over data modeling.  Intent was not to generalize, but to focus on this user's domain, based on what we have been told about it.

Comment: But still have a question. I have assumed that there are situations in which the domain model can only be affected because of technical constraints. Though it does not make much sense, if you think there are billions of comments associated with a single post, then the first model is thought to be a performance problem, so I came up with a second model. Of course, your advice to change mindset is a lot to me, but in this case I do not have to change mindset because of technical problems ....? I'm very confusing ...

Comment: ".... domain will constantly evolve with your understanding of the domain ....". After reading your answer several times, I realize your point of view. Thank you for your advice, references.

Comment: @hynsu - You will find that there will often be times when your domain model will lead you to technical challenges.  And, while you will strive to keep technical concerns outside of your domain, there is nothing wrong with discussing technical implications with the product owners.  The balance is doing it in a way that both parties can understand.  If there were billions of comments for a post, for example, it is something that could be argued that there is no business value as those comments could never logically be presented, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One pitfall I notice about people entering the DDD world is that they visualize their ARs as source of READ operations as well. So, many times they tend to "model" the ARs and its entities/value objects in a way that "appeals" a DTO that is meant to hydrate the UI.

In your case, I would make Post an AR and Comments another AR. Adding a comment shouldn't require to instantiate Post at all. Editing a Post shouldn't require to 'load' the comments at all.

Use an independent mechanism to project your post/comments into a POCO/DTO class that may make sense to have a collection of comments in your post.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Exactly. As you say, I have implemented comments as an aggregate. Also, when publishing to the outside, I make DTO separately and send it. I am just .... too confused as to how to accept that the domain model is inevitably affected by technical problems.

Comment: @hyunsu.... Confusion is the root of DDD learners. It tends to be confusing. Only when you read 2 or 3 times the same book and write over and over DDD-styled code is that you finally get it. Don't worry. Rant your frustration away if you need to. Venting out is not a crime :D